# Cookie with Express & NextJS

Tags: javascript, express, next.js, cookies

I'm using a Node/Express API on domain A and a NextJS 14 (using app rooter) application on domain B both hosted by Vercel.

In my API when I log in from my NextJS application I create a JWT that I send back via a cookie named "token" :

```
const login = async (req, res, next) => {
    const { pseudo, password } = req.body;

    if (!pseudo || !password) {
        return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Pseudo and password are required' });
    }
    
    try {
        // Check if user exists
        const user = await UserModel.findOne({ pseudo }).lean().exec();
        if (!user) {
            return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Pseudo or password is wrong' });
        }

        // Check if password is correct
        const passwordValid = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
        if (!passwordValid) {
            return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Pseudo or password is wrong' });
        }

        // Create JWT (expire in 1 day)
        const token = jwt.sign({ pseudo }, SECRET_TOKEN, { expiresIn: '1d' });

        // Set cookie
        res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', `token=${token}; Max-Age=${3600 * 24}; Path=/; HttpOnly; SameSite=None; Secure; Partitioned;`)
        //res.cookie('token', token, { maxAge: 3600 * 24 * 1000, httpOnly: true, sameSite: 'none', secure: true, partitioned: true });

        res.status(200).json({ message: 'Login successful', user: user.pseudo });
    } catch (error) {
        next(error);
    }
}
```

- 1st problem, Chrome blocks my cookie if I use "res.cookie".
  I did some research and came across this page:
  https://developers.google.com/privacy-sandbox/blog/cookie-countdown-2023oct

I deduced that I needed to add the “Partitioned” attribute to my cookie. Except that it's not managed by Express if I'm not saying something stupid (I tried the "partitioned: true" in res.cookie setting on any chance).

So I tested with `res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', '[...]; Partitioned')`... and the cookie is accepted by the browser, ok :

[cookie in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljwIR.png)

In my NextJS application, I have an "/admin" page when I am logged in.

In "app/admin/layout.js" file, I check authentication :

```
import { cookies } from 'next/headers';
import { redirect } from 'next/navigation';
import axios from '@/lib/axios';

export default async function Layout({ children }) {
    // Get cookie token
    const cookieStore = cookies()
    const token = cookieStore.get('token');
    
    if (token) {
        try {
            await axios.post('/auth/check', {}, { headers: { Cookie: `token=${token.value}` } });
        } catch (error) {
            redirect('/');
        }
    } else {
        redirect('/');
    }

    return (
        <>
            Something
        </>
    );
}
```

- 2nd problem, `token` variable from `cookieStore.get('token')` is undefined... However, the cookie "token" is stored in the browser. There's probably something I don't understand or haven't done correctly.

Thanks if you have any ideas.

I've tried so many random things that I don't think there's any point in talking about them here.

Comment: Can you try logging `cookieStore.getAll()` and see if there is any value?